# When and what was the first proof $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable?

Tags: set-theory, ho.history-overview

It seems the history of the interesting fact that there is no bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, Cantor's diagonalization trick in the mid 1800s, is common knowledge. Meanwhile, there are dozen(s) of clever proofs of the equally interesting fact that there *is* a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, but which proof was first and what was the story behind it?

Comment: Certainly Cantor knew (and proved/wrote down) that the set of all algebraic numbers is countable; this was in 1874, see: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor's_first_set_theory_article. It's hard to imagine any earlier proof because people didn't really think about countability before Cantor.

Comment: Cantor's diagonalization, of course, was not his first proof of uncountability of the reals.  I thought he proved rationals were countable in same paper that he introduced countability and also proved the reals are uncountable (via perfect sets).

Comment: The following is among Wikipedia's best articles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor%27s_first_set_theory_article

Comment: "Common knowledge" of history among mathematicans is often false. Cantor's diagonalization trick did not appear until some time after his first proof of uncountability of the reals.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You have mentioned your theory on that matter in several posts, but I don't really agree with your position. Cantor's first proof was indeed essentially a diagonalizaton, and essentially the same proof as the common proof given in his name now. He shrunk intervals so as successively to avoid the next point in a countable set, and thereby found a point different from all of them. But insisting on a certain digit in the decimal representation of a number is essentially the same as shrinking an interval so as to avoid the endpoint of an interval. It is the same argument each time.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins : Although I agree that the basic idea of the proof is the same, the word "diagonalization" invokes, in most non-experts' minds, a literal geometric diagonal. So there is a psychological difference, and I'm not even sure that the word "diagonalization" would have been coined without an explicit visual picture of a diagonal (and that explicit visual picture is not present in the original proof).

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins : Can you phrase Cantor's original proof in language that would make it obvious to a person who'd never seen it or any diagonal arguments before, that some kind of "diagonal" is being used? If so, it might be a worthwhile expository article.

Comment: "The bell rings." "The bell rang." "The bell has rung." "The athlete swims." "The athlete swam." "The athlete has swum." "The man sings." "The man sang." "The man has sung." That same sequence of three vowels used in just that way occurs in many Germanic strong verbs in English and German (and I suspect Dutch and Danish....). Yet with "sink" and "shrink" I've seen a different usage appearing in recent years. So @JoelDavidHamkins is that way of conjugating "shrink" something you insist on?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins : To me "diagonal" suggests the two components in an ordered pair are equal.

Comment: (Sorry about my grammatical error; I hope you can overlook it.) My mathematical point is that to specify the first finitely many digits of a real number is exactly to restrict to a certain interval, and this is the sense in which the arguments are the same. The digit method is simply an elementary or even elegant way to describe what is going on in Cantor's original argument.

Comment: I don't believe that one ever needs to use the word "diagonal" in either the original proof or the one involving digits. The main point is that you exclude the $n^{th}$ point at the $n^{th}$ stage of the construction. Since the points $(n,n)$ form a diagonal in the plane, we now describe all such arguments as diagonal arguments.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I rather side with you on all this, but the grammatical criticism really wasn't helpful.

Comment: One bare question (which I think has to be considered to make such a question relevant) is: when was the notion of countability exhibited? when was it given a name? was Cantor the first to unveil it and when? From [Nik Weaver's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/260647/14094) it seems that in November of 1973 Cantor had the concept in mind and that it didn't yet have a name.

Comment: The answer and comments are entirely about $\mathbb R$ not $\mathbb Q$, so the question should be changed accordingly. What can its mathematical content be for $\mathbb Q$? (a) Unique reducibility to lowest terms, which is in Euclid and (b) giving a name to the notion of countability, which has surely been known throughout history, with $\mathbb Q$ as an example that hardly needs much proof. If you want to be picky, make that example any decidable subset of $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 5):

From the Wikipedia article [Cantor's first set theory article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor%27s_first_set_theory_article) [cited](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260629/when-and-what-was-the-first-proof-mathbbq-is-countable#comment643330_260629) by Michael Hardy:

> On November 29, 1873, Cantor asked Dedekind whether the collection of positive integers and the collection of positive real numbers "can be corresponded so that each individual of one collection corresponds to one and only one individual of the other?" Cantor added that collections having such a correspondence include the collection of positive rational numbers, and collections of the form $(a_{n_1, n_2, \ldots , n_ν})$ where $n_1, n_2, \ldots , n_ν$, and $ν$ are positive integers.

That tells you when, and given the juxtaposition with the last assertion together with his published proof that the algebraic numbers are countable, I think you can infer how the proof he had in mind probably went. (Define the *height* of a positive fraction $\frac{p}{q}$ written in lowest terms to be the number $p + q$, observe that there are only finitely many fractions of a given height, and enumerate by height.)